# Enable or Disable Keyboard Short-cut Keys in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

Is there a function in photoshop to "Enable or Disable" The Keyboard Shortcut Keys. Because sometimes my Keyboard Stops working and when I Close and re-open the application it works Perfectly. I have felt this problem many times not in a particular Machine but several time in Different machines so I am pretty sure its not my Keyboard's defect.

Comment: Nope. [There are quite a few ways to try and solve this issue](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-stop-photoshop-mac.html).

Comment: The same problem occurred with me while using photoshop through RDC(remote desktop connection). I solved it by minimizing RDC window and maximizing it.

Comment: @Joonas Thanks joonas that was quite helpful.

Comment: @Dr. .Net will Definetly try this next time

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have tested this, but you can create new sets of shortcuts. Technically you could create a set that has all shortcuts deleted and flick that on and then back to the original.

Might give you the refresh you are after!